# I am having trouble understanding what is meant when the output of a matrix decoder is in the set of all real numbers

Tags: convolution, neural-networks

I am going through the equations of a research paper that describes the restoration of old films and came across the following equation:

$$y_t=D(s_t\frown\bar{s_t})\in\mathbb{R}^{W \times H}.$$

The result is a single recovered image matrix where the D represents a decoder network who's input is a concatenation of two encoded hidden states. I am having difficulties understanding what is meant by the second part of the equation.

My first thought was that it is constricting the bounds of the result to fit within the height and width of the original image that is being recovered.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just saying that the output of the function will be a $W \times H$ matrix of real numbers, i.e. it has one numeric output for each pixel in the image.

Comment: @ConMan That makes sense, I figured it had something to do with the dimensions, but I am unfamiliar with the notation. I appreciate the answer!

Comment: Yes, $x \in S$ is notation for "$x$ is an element of $S$", and $\mathbb{R}^{W \times H}$ is a fairly typical way of referring to the set of real-valued matrices of dimension $W \times H$.